# What's the best regression for this dataset?

Tags: regression

I don't have too strong of a stats background, so was hoping to get guidance on what kind of regression I should run if both my dependent and independent variables are binary (e.g. independent variable is whether the child had ice cream or not, and the dependent variable is whether the child got the flu).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Logistic regression.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [Bernoulli naive Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Bernoulli_naive_Bayes) model, if you want the most focused model. You will probably have more luck finding support in your favorite toolkit for logistic regression, which would also be appropriate but is slightly more general than what you need.